# WPF MVVM - Initialization and Binding (Get method)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

During the initialization of a View and it's respective ViewModel the WPF calls all the 'Get' methods from the Properties that have a Binding with a View Component.

Can I prevent the WPF from calling the Get methods during the initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because thats how the bindings initialize (unless they are `OneWayToSource`, but if they were I doubt you would think this was a problem)! However, you can just not set `DataContext` until later. Setting that *should* fire `DataContextChanged` and cause your bindings to update.

In all reality though, why do you want to do this? `PropertyChanged` is designed for handling the changes that occur after initialization.

Comment: My problem is that I have 2 tabs under one Window, and one of them have a Get that uses a Database connection. So, the problem is that the Get was being called before the user can configure the Database using the GUI. I can, of course, handle the connection exception to the user, but I was thinking if there's a workaround using the properties call only.

And thanks for the answer, it's all clear now!

Comment: @LucasReal a property getter really shouldn't be doing something so complicated as a database connection. That should be handled in the model, and loaded into the VM asynchronously.